# Using AJAX to submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http-post

I have developed a Python API and am now integrating it with a HTML template I have downloaded. It is a simple one page HTML template with a form to accept a album name and artist name. I am looking to process the form using AJAX. So once the form has been successfully submitted, it is replaced with a message returned by the API.

The (simplified) html snippet is:

```
<div class="form">
    <form role="form" action="form.php" id="signup">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Artist Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tracking Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="album" class="album">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then I have a JS file I import at the beginning of the html file. Below is the JS file.

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#signup');

    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {
            'artist'    : $('input[name=artist]').val(),
            'album'             : $('input[name=album]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'form.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json' 
    }) 
        .done(function(data) {
                var content = $(data).find('#content');
                $("#result").empty().append(content);
            });
});
```

I think the issue is with the `.done(function(data))` however, the website I found the code on wasn't clear.

form.php returns a JSON string. At the moment when I use the form, it sends the information to the Python API and the Python API returns a JSON message. But I cannot access the JSON message. It is in contains

```
'code': X, 'message':'returned messaged...'
```

ideally I would like to do a if/else statement. So

```
if code = 1:
    display: Success
```

etc but I have no idea where to start with it in PHP/JS.

Comment: remove form tag and leave the input and button tags, form is submitting itself when you click on the button. If you don't want to remove the form then simply add this `onsubmit=return false;` to the form tag.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen - I don't believe you've outlined your expectations in your post. Also, you're not parsing your returned data at any point.

Comment: @11thdimension The form is not submitting itself when he presses the button. It calls a form submit action, but is blocked by the `e.preventDefault`, no?

Comment: It still loads the form.php page and displays the json instead of adding it to the original index.html

Comment: then either errors are being thrown somewhere or form doesn't exist when page loads. What does your console show you?

Comment: @19421608 , in the submit function at the end add `return false`

Comment: Also, there is no need for an `action` on your form, being as you're explicitly defining it in your AJAX call.

Comment: @11thdimension `e.preventDefault()` is more reliable and will do same thing

Comment: @charlietfl yes, but he says it's still loading.

Comment: @11thdimension if `e.preventDefault()` gets called it's not going to submit...period. Doubling up won't help...more likely that it's not being called

Comment: First time using JS -didn't even realise there was a console. I opened it up there and got a syntax error which has been fixed. Now, it appears nothing happens on the website but the python backend accepted the input and return the json

Comment: Since it returns JSON, have you tried: `var cod = data.code; ` and  `var msg = data.message; `  to get the information you need?

Comment: @DouglasCamargo I have tried: 'var code = data.code;
          echo code;' but it comes up as syntax error.

Comment: @DouglasCamargo I have managed to find the solution in another Stack Overflow answer when combined with another website. I'll answer my own question in a few minutes for other newbies who might come across this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working eventually after seeing a few other stack overflow answers and another website.

I added one div to the html file under the button before the end of the form to make:

```
<form>
    ...
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit!</button>
    <div id="thanks" style="display:none;"></div>
</form>
```

Then, in the JS file I amended .done(function(data)) to be:

```
.done(function(data) {
            if (data.result == '1') {
                $('#thanks').show().text("Success!");
                $('input[type="text"],text').val('');
            } else if (data.result == '2') {
                $('#thanks').show().text("Album and Artist already exists");
            } else {
                $('#thanks').show().text("Uh Oh. Something has gone wrong. Please try again later or contact me for more help");
            }
        });
```